# Changes gets lost when several developers work on the same file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We're having some trouble with changes getting lost in our repository. It usually happens like the following:

- Developer A commits some changes to file A
- Days, weeks or months later, Developer B makes some changes to file A and commits.
- All changes made by developer A has been reverted. When doing a diff, it looks like developer B has manually reverted the changes although he hasn't.

What could be going on here?

Edit: It only happens when Developer B commits.

Answer (score 0):

Probably developer B didn't update his working copy before committing his stuff and/or ignored the messages telling him that he needs to merge his local changes with those that developer committed in the first place.

Comment: I tried this in a test repository and if I try to commit without updating I get a Commit failed error. Theses are non conflicting changes by the way.